# refresh all browser tabs using jquery or js

Tags: javascript, browser, refresh, page-refresh

The following function is for removing the cookie from browser. 
I want to refresh pages/tabs in the browser after clearing the cookie.
How to refresh all browser tabs after clearing the cookies?

```
 var removeAllCookies = function () {
  chrome.cookies.getAll({}, function (all_cookies) {

            var count = all_cookies.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {   
                 chrome.cookies.remove({"url": url, "name": all_cookies[i].name});

               }
            chrome.tabs.reload()
        });
}
```

Comment: this can be achieved by creating a chrome extension only! refer to https://superuser.com/questions/294656/refresh-all-tabs-in-google-chrome

Answer (score 0):

Gets all tabs that have the specified properties, or all tabs if no properties are specified using `chrome.tabs.query`

**Syntax:**

```
chrome.tabs.query(object queryInfo, function callback)
```

Just try this code:

```
chrome.tabs.query({windowType:'normal'}, function(currtabs) 
{
    for(let i=0;i<currtabs.length;i++) 
    {
        chrome.tabs.update(currtabs[i].id,{url:currtabs[i].url});
    }
});
```

Comment: could you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61077492/need-to-refresh-the-page-after-removing-cookie